# How do I fix a "column of relation does not exist" error in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

NB: See solution at the bottom of this post.

I'm just getting started with PostgreSQL, and am encountering a bizarre error that indicates severe pilot error and I'd love some advice on how to fix. When I try to add a row in my table, it tells me that the column that I wish to populate doesn't exist:

I create my table thus:

```
CREATE TABLE hsm
(
   id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() PRIMARY KEY,
   name text,
   contains text[],
   contained_by text[]
);
```

And the output of \d hsm:

```
    Table "public.hsm"
     Column      |  Type  | Collation | Nullable |      Default       
-----------------+--------+-----------+----------+--------------------
    id           | uuid   |           | not null | uuid_generate_v4()
    name         | text   |           |          | 
    contains     | text[] |           |          | 
    contained_by | text[] |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "hsm_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree ("   id")
```

Output of \d

```
     List of relations
 Schema |   Name   | Type  | Owner 
--------+----------+-------+-------
 public | hsm      | table | hsm
 public | hsm_test | table | hsm
```

\dn:

```
  List of schemas
  Name  |  Owner   
--------+----------
 public | postgres
(1 row)
```

\du:

```
Role name |                         Attributes                         | Member of 
-----------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 hsm       | Superuser, Create role, Create DB                          | {}
 postgres  | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

\dn+:

```
                          List of schemas
  Name  |  Owner   |  Access privileges   |      Description       
--------+----------+----------------------+------------------------
 public | postgres | postgres=UC/postgres+| standard public schema
        |          | =UC/postgres         |
```

Output of psql -V:

```
psql (PostgreSQL) 12.14 (Ubuntu 12.14-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)
```

Output of select attname, length(attname) from pg_attribute where attrelid = 'hsm'::regclass;:

```
     attname     | length 
-----------------+--------
 cmax            |      4
 cmin            |      4
 ctid            |      4
 tableoid        |      8
 xmax            |      4
 xmin            |      4
    contained_by |     15
    contains     |     11
    id           |      5
    name         |      7
(10 rows)
```

But when I enter the following to add a row:

```
insert into hsm (name)
     values (test);
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  column "name" of relation "hsm" does not exist
LINE 1: insert into hsm (name)
```

EDIT:

Output from \l:

```
    List of databases
   Name    |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |   Access privileges   
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------
 hsm       | hsm      | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 postgres  | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | 
 template0 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1 | postgres | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres          +
           |          |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
```

SOLUTION:

Somehow, I had three leading spaces at the start of my column names; note that these were not shown by commands such as "/d hsm" but did mean that there was no match between "   name" and "name".

These spaces seem to have been introduced through indentation; as to whether they came from copied code online or entered manually myself (who learned to code on Python), I can't remember. Either way, take note that: 1. Leading space characters are incorporated into variable names; 2. These leading spaces are not included in many outputs. They key here was the output of:

```
attname, length(attname) from pg_attribute where attrelid = 'hsm'::regclass;
```

Which showed that all my column names were three characters longer than they should have been.

Comment: Maybe the error is in the string (without quotes) that you are trying to insert, try this  `insert into hsm (name) values ('test');`

Comment: It works for me so I won't be able to tell what happens for you, but I must say `name` is a slightly poor choice to name a column as it is also a type (found, for instance in `SELECT usename from pg_user`), hence a reserved keyword.

Comment: I hear that, that said, all my columns throw the same error.

Comment: Could it be you have several tables called `hsm` in separate schemas? and the non-qualified `hsm` of your query refers to an unintended one? Try `insert into public.hsm ...`, perhaps. It would be strange to me but maybe not completely impossible... See [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) too.

Comment: Thanks for the theory! This is the output of \l:

                                  List of databases
   Name    |  Owner  
-----------+----------+--
 hsm       | hsm     
 postgres  | postgres 
 template0 | postgres
 template1 | postgres

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to paste the output. It seems I have only one database named hsm, is there another way to check if there is more than one schema?

Comment: "public.hsm" and public.hsm are two very different tables. What table did you really create?

Comment: I used the command: "CREATE TABLE hsm [...]" 

I'm too green to understand how public. fits in. public.hsm when used in the INSERT command yields the column not found error; "public.hsm" when used in the INSERT command yields a relation not found error.

Comment: When you say "this is the output of \d", I guess you mean `\d hsm`? What is the output of `\d`? And `\dn` (which I guess was what you actually wanted to do instead of `\l`)?

Comment: Yes! I've corrected and added just \d. NB: the hsm_test relation is one I created just now to see if the issue was several schemas by the name hsm.

Comment: Apologies! INSERT with public.hsm throws the same error. See output of \dn in post -- misread your earlier message and put from \d instead.

Comment: This rules out the possibility of having several hsm in separate schema. I see the owner is `hsm`. Could you try running your insert command as the super user? So that we can rule out something caused by missing privileges? Maybe output (`SELECT * FROM information_schema.column_privileges WHERE table_schema = 'public' AND table_name = 'hsm' AND column_name = 'name'`)

Comment: hsm is a super user (not planning this in production, obviously, just testing).

The output of that command is a table with 0 rows.

Comment: If you really are connected as a super user and it still does not work, I suggest you mention it in the question (add `\du` and `\dn+` instead of `\dn`). I am out of idea now, but with the additional details we reviewed together, it may help someone else figure it out.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I have added those new outputs to the post!

Comment: To your question add Postgres version, output of `psql -V`,  OS and version and how you installed Postgres.

Comment: Also run `select attname, length(attname) from pg_attribute where attrelid = 'hsm'::regclass;` to see if maybe there is a hidden character issue.

Comment: You have 3 leading spaces on each of the column names you created for the table. Best guess this comes from wherever you created the `CREATE TABLE ...` script.